# C#: Why my ProgressBar doesn't run several times?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I want to implement 2 progress bars into my WPF-application. One (ProgressbarDocument) shall show the progress of every chosen document and the other(ProgressbarProcess) shall show the progress of the whole process, that includes the treatment of every chosen document.
My Problem is, that the animation of the progress bars stops if they have a value of 100, but the animation of ProgressbarDocument isn't reset and restarted.
How can I do this?

```
double summand = (1 / anzahl);

Duration durationdocument = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Duration durationprocess = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(anzahl));

DoubleAnimation doubleanimationdocument = new DoubleAnimation(ProgressbarDocument.Value, durationprocess);
DoubleAnimation doubleanimationprocess = new DoubleAnimation(ProgressbarProcess.Value, durationprocess);

for (int j = 0; j <= anzahl; j++ )
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      ProgressbarDocument.Value++;
      ProgressbarProcess.Value= summand + ProgressbarProcess.Value;

      doubleanimationdocument = new DoubleAnimation(ProgressbarDocument.Value, durationdocument);
      doubleanimationprocess = new DoubleAnimation(ProgressbarProcess.Value, durationprocess);
      ProgressbarDocument.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimationdocument);
      ProgressbarProcess.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimationprocess);
   }
   if(ProgressbarDocument.Value==100)
   {
      ProgressbarDocument.Value = 0;
      ProgressbarDocument.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimationdocument);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use >= instead of ==

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger to see whether `ProgressbarDocument.Value = 0;` gets called?

Comment: Just set your ProgressbarDocument to the modulo of your value with 100.

Comment: O.R. Mapper: Yes, `ProgressbarDocument.Value = 0` gets called. That's why I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` will exit after i was 99. i == 100 is never called, thus your if-Statement `if(ProgressbarDocument.Value==100)` never matches.

I assume you wanted your for loop to run until 100:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
```

Comment: Maybe you should not use those double animations here. You're setting up way too many animations (for each little step) - you should use one animation for the whole progress.

Comment: and how can I do this?